# Getting error trying to deploy a sharepoint 2010 workflow package from Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, nintex-workflow

I'm trying to deploy a Nintex Sharepoint workflow from Visual Studio 2010, on a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 machine, running Sharepoint 2010, and I keep getting this error:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is not installed on this system. It is required to perform this operation.

Any ideas what the problem might be or how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I kind of stumbled across the answer. I found a couple people who addressed similar issues by disabling .NET Framework 3.5.1 in Windows Features.
I turned the feature off, rebooted and it works. No more error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that as the error states, you need to install Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 on you machine. You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22

Comment: Sorry, that answer does not apply because I'm on Windows 7 and .NET 3.5 SP1 is built in. Besides, I've tried to run the SP1 installer several times and it doesn't work.